# Debugging a console exe with VS2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have an exe which I run using command line. I pass arguments to the exe and program execution completes. Now I am looking to debug this process to understand the program flow. Though I run the exe from command line, I would like to debug it in Visual Studio 2013. 
I am very new to C# and Visual Studio and not much aware of debugging options. I have come to know about "Attach to Process" option in visual studio, but my exe runs very fast and does not leave any time to attach the process for debugging. Please could you suggest me a good way to debug?

Comment: Do you have the source code to this exe? If not, what do you expect to get out of "debugging it"?

Comment: decompile it? then debug the source code?

Answer (score 1):

To debug exe one easy way is to open exe as "project" (File->open project), setup command line arguments via properties and start debugging (I'm not sure which flavor of VS allows that so hopeful you have one that can do so).

How useful it would be depends on your goals and what you have. You can debug any EXE native and look at assembly, you can debug managed EXE and will be able to get some symbols. If you have source and matching PDBs you may actually step through the code...

Comment: Although unlikely to help OP, I'd mention [mdbg](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229861%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for completeness.

Comment: @zespri OP asked about VS... But indeed it is another option. As well as WinDbg+SOS (assuming OP actually have managed exe, also there is no indication of it in question except C# tag which may or may not be related).

Answer (score 0):

**If you got source code**, 
you can simply hit F5 or call `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();` before the block you which you like to debug.

**I if you don't have source code**,
you could use [IlSpy](http://ilspy.net/) to get it. With ILSpy you can get IL, VB or C# code from an EXE or DLL file. You can save the code as Visual Studio-Project and open and debug it the way mentioned above. Expect that the code maybe is obfuscated.